# UIActivityIndicator in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell like this:

```
// Custom.h
@interface CustomQuestionCell : UITableViewCell {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *mywebView;

}

-(void) AssignWebView:(NSString *) _text;

// Custom.m
-(void) AssignWebView:(NSString *) _text {


    [mywebView loadHTMLString:_text baseURL:nil];

}
```

I can successfully use the UITableViewCell in UITableView in file called MainViewController. The delegate of UITableViewCell is MainViewController.  In MainViewController I am calling below code to assign value to UIWebView.

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath
//CustomQuestionCel.xib uses the class Custom defined above.

CustomQuestionCell *cell = (CustomQuestionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomQuestionCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tblQuestionCell;
}

[cell AssignWebView:[ListOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

My question is:

I would like to display an activity indicator in each cell while the UIWebView is loading the data.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In your `CustomQuestionCell` header (.h file):

```
@interface CustomQuestionCell : UITableViewCell <UIWebViewDelegate> {
   IBOutlet UIWebView *mywebView;
   IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *mySpinner;
}
```

**2.** In your `CustomQuestionCell` implementation (.m file):

```
- (void) AssignWebView:(NSString *) _text {
    [myWebView setDelegate:self];
    [mywebView loadHTMLString:_text baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [myWebView setHidden:YES];
    [mySpinner startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [mySpinner stopAnimating];
    [myWebView setHidden:NO];
}
```

**3.** In your `CustomQuestionCellView` nib file insert a spinner (`UIActivityIndicatorView`). Connect it as an `mySpinner` outlet to your `File's Owner`. Check `Hides when stopped` checkbox and uncheck `Animating` one.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. The code works fine but does not resolve the problem I am having. When I slide up /down the tableview, the content of the text which gets loaded from the UIwebview overlaps up for sometime. If I keep the screen with no movement(slide up or down) , the the content of the text aligns its self properly. Any idea how to resolve this. Thanks again for checking into my question.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. :) What is your cell supposed to do?

Comment: In the function for "cellForRowAtIndexPath .." for tabeleview (which s present in the MainViewController) I am assiging the values for the UIwebview using the function 

[cell AssignWebView:[ListOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

the string that is sent for UIwebview is very long..might be 50-100 words or more than that sometimes. EVerything works fine , but if the rows created is more than 1 , then scrolling through the tableview will make the cell content overlap for few seconds and then it sets itself properly.

Comment: Here is the link to my new question which explains the problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632596/find-uiwebview-height-dynamically-when-inside-uitableviewcell

Comment: OK, I answered there. But if this answer was helpful and solved the problem of UIActivityIndicator, you can accept it ;)