# Find UIWebView height dynamically when inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell like this

```
// CustomQuestionCell.h
@interface CustomQuestionCell : UITableViewCell {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *mywebView;

}

-(void) AssignWebView:(NSString *) _text;

// CustomQuestionCell.m
-(void) AssignWebView:(NSString *) _text {

     [mywebView setDelegate:self];
    [mywebView loadHTMLString:_text baseURL:nil];

}
```

I can successfully use the UITableViewCell in UITableView in file called MainViewController. The delagate of UITableViewCell is CustomQuestionCell.  In MainViewController I am calling below code to assign value to UIwebview.

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath
//CustomQuestionCel.xib uses the class CustomQuestionCell defined above.

CustomQuestionCell *cell = (CustomQuestionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomQuestionCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tblQuestionCell;
}

[cell AssignWebView:[ListOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];



return cell;
```

I also have the following delegate code in CustomQuestionCell.m

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"webview frame size %f",aWebView.frame.size.height);
    [aWebView setOpaque:NO];
    [aWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255 green:243.0/255 blue:236.0/255 alpha:1.0]];

    [activityLoad stopAnimating];
    [mywebView setHidden:NO];
}
```

My problem is I am not able to set the  the height of the cell properly in MainViewController which has tableView which uses the custom cell "CustomQuestionCell". In the function

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in MainViewController how can I set the height of the cell as aWebView.frame.size.height ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way (I think) is create a delegate.

**1. `CustomQuestionCell.h`**

```
@protocol CustomQuestionCellDelegate;

@interface CustomQuestionCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *mywebView;
    id <CustomQuestionCellDelegate> *delegate;
}

- (void)checkHeight;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <CustomQuestionCellDelegate> *delegate;

@end

@protocol CustomQuestionCellDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)customQuestionCell:(CustomQuestionCell *)cell shouldAssignHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight;

@end
```

**2. `CustomQuestionCell.m (webViewDidFinishLoad:)`**

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
    CGRect frame = aWebView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    aWebView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [aWebView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    aWebView.frame = frame;

    NSLog(@"webview frame size %f",aWebView.frame.size.height);
    [aWebView setOpaque:NO];
    [aWebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255 green:243.0/255 blue:236.0/255 alpha:1.0]];

    [activityLoad stopAnimating];
    [mywebView setHidden:NO];
}

- (void)checkHeight {
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customQuestionCell:shouldAssignHeight:)]) {
        [self.delegate customQuestionCell:self shouldAssignHeight:aWebView.frame.size.height];
    }
}
```

**3. `MainViewController.m (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`**

```
CustomQuestionCell *cell = (CustomQuestionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomQuestionCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = tblQuestionCell;
}

cell.delegate = self; // <-- add this

[cell AssignWebView:[ListOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

if([[didReloadRowsBools objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] boolValue] != YES) {
    [cell checkHeight];
}

return cell;
```

**4. `MainViewController.m (add theese methods wherever you want)`**

```
- (void)customQuestionCell:(CustomQuestionCell *)cell shouldAssignHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [cellHeights setObject:newHeight forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    [didReloadRowsBools setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
    if([cellHeights objectForKey:key] == nil) {
        return 44; // change it to your default height
    } else {
        return [cellHeights objectForKey:key];
    }
}
```

**5. `MainViewController.h`**

```
#import "CustomQuestionCell.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <CustomQuestionCellDelegate> {

    NSMutableDictionary *cellHeights; // <-- add this
    NSMutableDictionary *didReloadRowsBools; <-- and this

}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Kashiv for giving me sample code. I tried this code..but the cellrow creation is going on an infinte loop. Any idea how it can be fixed.

Comment: I like the delegate idea, since you're subclassing UITableViewCell. I don't see why you're using an NSMutableDictionary as opposed to NSMutableArray though since you're using indexPath.row as the key anyway. Not sure what is causing the infinite loop, but perhaps a simple BOOL didReloadHeight would be a quick fix so it only reloads the cell once.

Comment: I tried the above code..but no luck yet. Looks like the code 
[didReloadRowsBools setObject:YES forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
is not setting the object value for the required key.

in the code


if([didReloadRowsBools objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] != YES) {
    [cell AssignWebView:[ListOfQuestions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

[didReloadRowsBools objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]] is NULL. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: OK, editem my code again. I forgot that I can't store booleans in NSDictionary. It has to be converted into NSNumber.

Comment: Thanks again Kashiv for responding. Your code helped me in resolving  infinite loop problem ..…but nothing shows up on the tabelViewcell. Its just empty ..!!! ANy idea why this is happening. Appreciate your help very much..!!!

Comment: @Kashiv I followed your guied, but got an error in method customQuestionCell, and the code is [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: @qichunren You must be doing something wrong. Check your indexPath object.

Comment: NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; always returns nil.. I am assuming thats because its called before we actually return a cell in cellforrow... Any suggestions?

Comment: @qichunren I am getting same error Have you find any solution ?

Comment: `webViewDidFinishLoad` called after `[cell checkHeight]`. So i can retrieve the webview heights. but cannot fetch those heights to the corresp cells. Help me plz.

Comment: @akashivskyy One question. Do you use a flag in order to avoid an infinite loop? Because if we reload a cell, then we are reloading the website again.

Answer (score 0):

I have not actually tried this, but I would have an NSMutableArray of float values for the heights. In webViewDidFinishLoad, assign to the array at the proper index with aWebView.frame.size.height, then reload that cell.

heightForRowAtIndexPath can then simply point to the the height array at index indexPath.row.