# Setting HTML text for UILabel in IB

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

Getting HTML text from back-end, now i am manually removing and formatting the tags and adding bullet points for `<li>` tags.

if any other `<p>` tag or `<br>` tag is coming means then i am removing it. Checked [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel), Unable to use this in Interface builder.

Now tried [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel), i am able to use this in IB but it is not recognizing the HTML tags.

is there any other lightweight library available?

Comment: You can try using a Webview instead of UILabel...Then you dont have to remove tags manually...Just a suggestion.

Comment: actually its a dynamic UITableView, if i use UIWebView then memory issues will come i guess, thats why i am using UILabel.

Comment: No No...Memory issues will not come....you can go with webview.

Comment: `WKWebView` is definitely the solution here. Don't do HTML parsing yourself

Comment: Did you see this notes https://github.com/codepath/objc_ios_guides/wiki/Generating-NSAttributedString-from-HTML ?
You can use NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType to convert HTML to NSAttributedString, but it could lead to short app freez for large html page. As I know it's can't be called from the background thread.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi i tried your suggestion, its working, but the performance is very slow, tableview is strucking.

Comment: i don't know how to set dynamic height for webview, i tried it now, it seems more complex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632596/find-uiwebview-height-dynamically-when-inside-uitableviewcell @NeerajSonaro and atMichael Hulet

Comment: In that notes, I see the link to DTCoreText. I don't use it but looks good. And this is a discussion about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/4652521/2739795

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204967/how-to-change-the-height-of-webview-dynamically
 Check this link

Comment: @NeerajSonaro thank you for the link you shared, I tried it, the performance is fine, but first time loading the cell webview content is going beyond the row height, while reloading it is fitting fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel) to display HTML text instead of UILabel. Please check below link for more details :-

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel

Comment: it is a dynamic uitableview, i cannot set the uilabel text programmatically. thats why i am unable to use this RTLabel library.

Comment: Ignore above comment. 

You can calculate height of RTLabel object and assigned height of the cell.
For eg :-

`RTLabel *lbl = [[RTLabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [lbl setText:@"<br> alloc </br>"];
        [lbl sizeToFit];`

`float fltLBLHeight = lbl.frame.size.height;`

Now we can get height of label and use it for dynamic height and assigned it in TableView delegate method "heightForRowAtIndexPath".

I hope this could help you !!!

Comment: i am not having only this label in my uitableviewcell, the dynamic label will come in between some objects, so i cannot do this by programmatically, previously i tried like this, it performed very slow, that's why using autolayout in IB.